# Obtener valores de un JSON usando destructuring

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy aprendiendo destructuring en JavaScript y quiero obtener del json el NOMBRE_UGL , DIRECCION , LOCALIDAD de attributes y de geometry x e y me podrían ayudar por favor. Gracias!

```
features: [
{
attributes: {
OBJECTID: 1,
ID_UGL: "1",
NOMBRE_UGL: "TUCUMAN",
ID_AGENCIA: "10000",
NOMBRE_AGENCIA: "UGL I - TUCUMAN",
DIRECCION: "SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO 1020 ",
LOCALIDAD: "SAN MIGUEL DE TUCUMAN",
X: -65.21076584,
Y: -26.82272171
},
geometry: {
x: -65.21076583687207,
y: -26.822721714275644
}
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar destructores simples o anidados, te dejo los siguientes ejemplos incluyendo el uso de los destructores para arreglos.

Tenemos la primera opción, en la cual usaremos lo que llamaré "destructores simples".

```js
const json = {
  features: [
    {
      attributes: {
        OBJECTID: 1,
        ID_UGL: '1',
        NOMBRE_UGL: 'TUCUMAN',
        ID_AGENCIA: '10000',
        NOMBRE_AGENCIA: 'UGL I - TUCUMAN',
        DIRECCION: 'SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO 1020 ',
        LOCALIDAD: 'SAN MIGUEL DE TUCUMAN',
        X: -65.21076584,
        Y: -26.82272171,
      },
      geometry: {
        x: -65.21076583687207,
        y: -26.822721714275644,
      },
    },
  ],
};

// Destructor de arreglos (Obtenemos la posición 0 en variable feature)
const [feature] = json.features;

// Destructor de objetos (Obtenemos propiedad NOMBRE_UGL dentro de attributes)
const { NOMBRE_UGL, DIRECCION, LOCALIDAD } = feature.attributes;
console.log('NOMBRE_UGL: ' + NOMBRE_UGL);
console.log('DIRECCION: ' + DIRECCION);
console.log('LOCALIDAD: ' + LOCALIDAD);

// Destructor de objetos (Obtenemos X y Y de geometry)
const { x, y } = feature.geometry;
console.log('x: ' + x);
console.log('y: ' + y);
```

Y la segunda opción que llamaré "destructores anidados".

```js
const json = {
  features: [
    {
      attributes: {
        OBJECTID: 1,
        ID_UGL: '1',
        NOMBRE_UGL: 'TUCUMAN',
        ID_AGENCIA: '10000',
        NOMBRE_AGENCIA: 'UGL I - TUCUMAN',
        DIRECCION: 'SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO 1020 ',
        LOCALIDAD: 'SAN MIGUEL DE TUCUMAN',
        X: -65.21076584,
        Y: -26.82272171,
      },
      geometry: {
        x: -65.21076583687207,
        y: -26.822721714275644,
      },
    },
  ],
};

// Destructor de arreglos (Obtenemos la posición 0 en variable feature)
const [feature] = json.features;

// Destructor anidado de objetos (Obtenemos las propiedades de attributes y geometry en una sola expresión)
const { attributes: { NOMBRE_UGL, DIRECCION, LOCALIDAD }, geometry: { x, y } } = feature;
console.log('NOMBRE_UGL: ' + NOMBRE_UGL);
console.log('DIRECCION: ' + DIRECCION);
console.log('LOCALIDAD: ' + LOCALIDAD);
console.log('x: ' + x);
console.log('y: ' + y);
```

> Nota: La segunda opción puede parecer un tanto llamativa al poder hacer todo en una sola línea, pero en situaciones complejas puede no ser viable por cuestiones de legibilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los ejemplos @Jose Noriega, era justo lo que necesitaba :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un objeto cuya propiedad `features` es un arreglo.  Te dejo un ejemplo de como accesar la propiedad `NOMBRE_UGL`:

```js
var json = {
features: [
{
attributes: {
OBJECTID: 1,
ID_UGL: "1",
NOMBRE_UGL: "TUCUMAN",
ID_AGENCIA: "10000",
NOMBRE_AGENCIA: "UGL I - TUCUMAN",
DIRECCION: "SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO 1020 ",
LOCALIDAD: "SAN MIGUEL DE TUCUMAN",
X: -65.21076584,
Y: -26.82272171
},
geometry: {
x: -65.21076583687207,
y: -26.822721714275644
}
}
]
};

console.log(json.features[0].attributes.NOMBRE_UGL);
```

Comment: gracias @alanfcm